# Custom normalisation from 0 to 20

Tags: algorithmic-trading, quants, algorithm, standard-deviation

I want to normalise from 0 to 20

For example right now I  do normalisation with dynamic outlier exclusion , using median.

So it works fine for some values like below

```
[100,200,19,0,200,200,12,19000,14000]
```

It is converted to

```
 [5, 10, 0.95, 0, 10, 0.6, 10, 10]
```

Which is good , I want do normalisation of values greater than median value which give score of 11 to 20 , Something like

```
  [5, 10, 0.95, 0, 10, 0.6, 20 , 16]
```

This is the code I use right now

```
   var upper_lim = median*2;
   var test =   10*Math.min(value, upper_lim )/upper_lim;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you are creating a mapping, or a function here.

In the first instance you had a maximal score of 10, and you mapped as follows:

$$f(volume) = \left \{ \begin{matrix}  10* volume/200, \quad volume < 200 \\ 10 * 1, \quad volume \geq 200 \end{matrix} \right .$$

You have coded this in JS as (where 200 is `upper_lim`):

```
var test =   10*Math.min(value, upper_lim )/upper_lim;
```

Now you have redefined your mapping to the following:

$$f(volume) = \left \{ \begin{matrix}  10* \frac{volume}{200}, \quad volume < 200 \\ 10 * (1 + \frac{volume-200}{19000-200}), \quad volume \geq 200 \end{matrix} \right .$$

where 19000 is `max_volume`. The maximum value this function can take is 20.

```
var test;
if (value < upper_lim)  {
  test = 10 * value / upper_limit 
} else {
  test = 10 * ( 1 + (value-upper_limit)/(max_value-upper_limit) )
}
```

Comment: var value = 150;
var upper_lim = 1275;
var max = 1425;
   
 var test = 10*Math.min(value/upper_lim, 1+(value-upper_lim)/(max-upper_lim));
test;
 I get -65 for this inputs.

Comment: I have made an adjustment - I'm sure you could have figured that out..

Comment: Thank you , you are genius.